# excel vba - Inserting data from userform to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form that draws information from a specific row. The user form uses vlookup to find the row using numbers that are in column A.

After presenting the data from the table in the user form:

- I want the person to be able to insert data back to the form from
  txtboxes
- in to the specific row (based on the number from the previous search
- in a specific column.

Then, if the cell in the column is not empty, move to the next free column and insert it there.

I hope my question is clear.

```
If Trim(TB_staus.Text) = "????" Then
    Worksheets("lists").Select
    Worksheets("lists").Range("A5").Select
    If Worksheets("lists").Range("a5").Offset(1, 0) = CMB_Cavityenter.Value Then
        Worksheets("lists").Range("a5").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Select
    acitvecell.Value = Date
Else 'do nothing
End If
```

Comment: i am strugling with the find formula to find the correct cell then placing the data inside i think i will manage.

Comment: Please merge your code with your initial question so it is readable

Comment: so what is the issue you have? You have a typo on `acitvecell.value = Date` should read `ActiveCell.Value = Date` That line and the one above could also be combined to remove the `Select` statements. If you explain where your issue is exactly someone might be able to help you more